# Server http:/localhost:8080 requires a user name and a password. The server says: XDB

Tags: tomcat, server, localhost

I am trying to access localhost:8080 but it is showing me I need to enter user name and pass word. I remember messing up with the server some 4 months ago while I was trying to develop a web application and hosting my domain name on my pc, Unfortunately I become unsuccessful. While working with servlets I was tring some security features and till some time i did not see and of these pop up windows asking for authentication.

I tried to enter the password that I was playing with but non of those are working. Is there anyway i could get out of this problem? [image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is http authentication. You can find username and password inside users.xml WEB-INF directory if any. otherwise you have to edit or remove `security-constraint` element from web.xml file

UPDATE
Sorry,
I haven't noticed XDB. check if Oracle and tomcat using same port. Update anyone of them

Comment: I am not trying to run any deployed application at this time but I am wondering why it is poping while i try to access localhost:8080

Comment: Yes now it is solved. The problem was from oracle database. Thank you all

Comment: please i have the same problem but i don't have any oracle database i tried to delete security-constraint but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @TesfaZelalem How did you resolve this? I too have oracle database..

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-do-i-change-default-port-apache-tomcat

Comment: I have multiple projects that work - only one of them pops up the Sign in dialog. Not running Oracle. Commented out the security settings, but fear Tomcat has possibly cached them somewhere, but I don't know where.

Answer (score 13):

Some other application(like oracle) is using the same port number. So you should change the tomcat port number in `apachetomcat/conf/server.xml`

Privious--->

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Updated ---->

```
<Connector port="8088" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Answer (score 6):

This is caused because there is a database running on your computer.
In my case, it was an Oracle data base. By default, everytime you start your computer, the services of the database automatically starts.

Go to Start >> find Oracle or whatever data-base in the list of programms >> and manually stop the database. It appears that there is a conflict of port.

Answer (score 4):

give username as `admin`

and leave the password empty

Answer (score 4):

Add username and password in application propreties files.

When adding spring security every http query must be authentified by login and password.

[image: See Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall WAMP/XAMPP and install it again with default port number. It will work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that uninstall and reinstall Tomcat is not acceptable to you.
The screen shot show basic auth challenge screen from browser and on the default app. So most likely you have set up users on the tomcat using the 
    conf/tomcat-users.xml 
Try going through this guide https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#UserDatabaseRealm

There are several other realms that you could have possibly used. Hopefully you will remember when you start reading the doc

Comment: But for me in this file, I have the user, password XML tags been commented out but still, I am getting the prompt asking for username and password.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file :

```
WEB-INF -> web.xml
```

In my case, it looks like as following.  :

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Integration Web Services</web-resource-name>
        <description>Integration Web Services accessible by authorized users</description>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>Roles that have access to Integration Web Services</description>
        <role-name>maximouser</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <description>Data Transmission Guarantee</description>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Remove or comment these lines.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, I just change the jboss7.1 port from 8080 to 9090. and it worked perfectly for me.
To change the jboss7.1 port go to `jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\configuration` open `standalone.xml` look for the line `<socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>` change `8080` to `9090`. save the file and
Restart the server. it should work

Answer (score 1):

even i faced the same problem.
The possibility of this could be usage of same port by two or more application/process.
In Some cases you can use different port number which will avoid this problem, but in other case you have to manually kill the process with help of command prompt.

The command to kill is,
In your command prompt first enter this command

C:\Users\A611003>tasklist

After this you can able to see list of process running with process ID. 
For example,
[image]

From this select the process you want to stop, for example consider the process id 304 is your server and you have problem with that.
Then enter this command.

```
C:\Users\A611003>Taskkill /PID 304 /F
```

This will kill that process now you can clean, publish your server and start it.

Note: If you fail to add /F in the above command it does nothing. It is the force kill. you can also try/? for list of available options.

Answer (score 1):

I think, Any other service like Database etc running on port 8080.

Please configure new port on your application and run on that port.

Answer (score 0):

I just killed the Oracle processes and re-initiate JBoss. All was fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your default port 8080 to something else like below example

```
SQL> begin
 2   dbms_xdb.sethttpport('9090');
 3   end;
 4  /
```

Comment: Worked for me.

I was actually using tomcat server installed in my computer and i just thought of start using spring boot. so, i removed tomcat from control panel but wen i hit localhost:8080 it was asking username and password. wen i ran this sql command in the cmd after connecting to sql. my problem got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the username and password details in your {tomcat installation directory}/conf/tomcat-users.xml

Answer (score 0):

Just change the port number used e.g. 8000 then call the  http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

The solution worked for me is to kill whatever process is running on port 8080 (in my case it was oracle) and then restart your server and run your project again.

Open Windows PowerShell and type these commands:

`netstat  -ano  |  findstr  <Port Number>`

[image]

`taskkill  /F  /PID  <Process Id>`

replace 'Process ID' with whatever number is shown in your terminal

[image]

After this, restart your server and run your project again and it should work.