# localhost:8080 requires login and password - tomcat + h2

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, h2

I saw other topics about it: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960741/server-http-localhost8080-requires-a-user-name-and-a-password-the-server-says), but I'm running in-memory DB H2 with Spring Boot and I don't know how I can change my H2 port. Is it the only way? Can't I have Tomcat AND database on the same port?

Answer (score 0):

No two process can run on same port. So, one of them you need to update. Better try changing tomcat port no.

Also, try login using tomcat credentials, it's possible your tomcat application is protected. Refer tomcat-users.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I had SpringSecurity added in POM.xml and when it's added Spring Boot automatically pre-configures some stuff - adds some security.

Added that configuration class and it works fine.

```
@Configuration
```

public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/")
            .permitAll();

    // disabling csrf tokens and x-frame-options to be able to run h2 console (localhost:8080/console)
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
    httpSecurity.headers().frameOptions().disable();
}
```

}